# Field value is null in SharePoint search REST API result

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-365, rest, search-api

I have simple search REST GET query as below :

```
https://<site url>/_api/search/query?querytext='research'&selectproperties='Title,Author,Created,ContentTypeId'
```

The search result XML returned is like below : 
[image]

But the 'Author' field is returned with a value null.

What could be a possible reason?

Comment: What shows up if you manually search for for these articles in the UI -- specifically when you mouse over these objects what is in the "Contributors Include" area? If there is no author on whatever it is you're looking at, that could be a reason it's showing up null. Everything in my environment seems to have something for the author though, even if it's just 'System Account'

Comment: Lookups need to be expanded. You can not simply select `Author`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the internal name of the fields matches the field name you are using in your request.  I've created an author field for a list doing something similar and the internal name defaulted to Author0 as Author already existed.

And if it is a lookup field you are using you'll have to use something like `Author/Name&$expand=Author/Name` in your request.

Comment: The 'Author' field in my case is the internal name of default SharePoint field whose display name is 'Created By'